# How to read information from connected HID devices in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, usb, windows-8.1

I need to read information from a mouse which connects to Windows 8.1 through Bluetooth in y Qt application. This is done to see that a new mouse is connected to the computer for testing purposes, so if I could read out e.g. the MAC address or something similiar that is unique for the device I would be good.

I have no experience with either C++ or Qt, so if someone has a working example that would be great. I've previously worked with C# and WinUSB, and found it quite tedious to figure these things out without having some examples to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't support such device detection. You need to process WM_DEVICECHANGE messages sent by Windows. There's an [FTDI App Note 152](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_152_Detecting_USB_%20Device_Insertion_and_Removal.pdf) that provides some insight, but it's shown using MFC, not Qt. In Qt, you'll need to implement a custom `QAbstractNativeEventFilter` and install it on the application by calling `qApp->installNativeEventFilter(myFilter)` to process windows messages.